# Android manifest error on android studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest

Today, when I start my project I am got an error like below I have already that classes in `java` folder but I can't run my project.

I tried this solution but it didn't work.

```
 sourceSets {
      main {
          manifest.srcFile 'ToDoList/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
      }
  }
  sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/<YOUR DIRECTORY>'
    }
```

[image]

Comment: do you have this all class in java folder??

Comment: yes i have already checked and its there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have facing same problem before  **Just change your project folder directory**  and **import again** that work for me.

Hope it work.....

Comment: @pratikgaikwad he getting error in android manifest file and also can not run

Comment: @ArpitPatel yes i did as u told and its works for me thank you